# SQL - Converting data to DateTime intervals

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm looking for some elegant SQL code that will read this

[image]

and create this

[image]

when given a parameter of @interval (minutes integer), in this case 30 minute intervals.

The amount of time logged in, based on the first table needs to be calculated and put into the second table for each 30 minute interval.

RDMBS is MS SQL Server.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You're saying you want to take a single row and round to the nearest `@interval` amount? i.e. `@interval = 15` so 7:46 becomes 7:45, 7:55 becomes 8:00, etc?

Comment: There is no universal SQL statement that will handle this problem.  What RDBMS are you using?  You need to update your question with that information if you want advice.

Comment: Sorry, my original post was unclear, but should be clear now.

Comment: RDMBS is MS SQL Server

Comment: You also need to clarify what happens if you have a login session of say 8 hours.  Does table2 get 16 rows then?

Comment: Yes, table2 will have all consecutive time intervals from the first login time through the last login time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the input data is stored in a table called dbo.inputData then the following T-SQL will give you what you want (and could easily be improved upon!)

```
create table dbo.outputData
(
    StartDateTime datetime not null,
    EndDateTime datetime not null
);

-- Seed the table
declare @maxDate as datetime =  dateadd(hour, 1, (select max(LoggedOutDateTime) from inputData));
with myCte as
(
    -- Truncate the smallest date to the hour
    select dateadd(hour, datediff(hour,0, min(LoginDateTime)),0) as StartDateTime
    from dbo.inputData
    union all
    select dateadd(minute, 30, StartDateTime)
    from myCte
    where StartDateTime <= @maxDate
)

insert into dbo.outputData(StartDateTime,EndDateTime)
select StartDateTime, dateadd(minute,30,StartDateTime)
from myCte;

-- Now do the actual calculations stuff
with myCte2 as
(
select o.StartDateTime, o.EndDateTime, i.LoginDateTime, i.LoggedOutDateTime,
    case when i.LoggedOutDateTime > o.EndDateTime then o.EndDateTime else i.LoggedOutDateTime end as rangeEnd,
    case when i.LoginDateTime > o.StartDateTime then i.LoginDateTime else o.StartDateTime end as rangeStart
from dbo.outputData as o
inner join dbo.inputData as i
    on i.LoggedOutDateTime > o.StartDateTime and 
        i.LoginDateTime < o.EndDateTime
)

select m.StartDateTime, m.EndDateTime, sum(DATEDIFF(SECOND,m.rangeStart, m.rangeEnd)) as secs
from myCte2 as m
group by m.StartDateTime, m.EndDateTime
```

Comment: Paul, this is exactly what I was looking for.  It works very well.  I replaced the "30" values with a variable @interval int so that it can be dynamic.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

In general, to assign a particular datetime value to a partition, it's simple date arithmetic:

```
declare @moment_in_time           datetime = current_timestamp
declare @today                    datetime = convert(date,@moment_in_time)
declare @bucket_length_in_seconds int      = 30 * 60
declare @buckets_per_day          int      = 24*60*60 / @bucket_length_in_seconds
declare @bucket_number            int      = datediff(second,@today,@moment_in_time)
                                           / @bucket_length_in_seconds
declare @bucket_start_time        datetime = dateadd(second,
                                               @bucket_length_in_seconds
                                               * ( datediff(second,@today,@moment_in_time)
                                                   /
                                                   @bucket_length_in_seconds
                                                 ) ,
                                               @today
                                               )

select moment_in_time    = @moment_in_time ,
       today             = @today ,
       buckets_per_day   = @buckets_per_day ,
       bucket_number     = @bucket_number ,
       bucket_start_time = @bucket_start_time
```

Exploding your source table into a row per bucket it covers is up to you. A hint: a sequence table consisting of a continuous sequence of integers ranging from, say, -1,000,000 to +1,000,000 comes in mighty useful sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

(Date1 - date2)*24*60= your interval in minutes